# Non-ohmic conductors

Tags: electrical-resistance, conductors, electronics

Non ohmic conductors are said to be the conductors that do not obey Ohm's Law. The V-I graph for them is not a straight line unlike ideal ohmic conductors.

According to me Ohm's Law states:
**The voltage across a conductor is directly proportional to the current in it** given that other factors such as temperature remain constant. ie.

$$R=V/I$$

I have also read that change in temperature due to heat dissipated is also a reason for varying V/I values for non ohmic conductors. My question is that,given this, how can  we say that a conductor doesn't obey Ohm's law. Shouldn't everything be having a constant voltage to current ratio at a given point in time (or an infinitesimal time interval). Similarly shouldn't the resistance be then defined to be the derivative of voltage with respect to current?

Comment: There are devices that have two different operating regions such that a given voltage applied may lead to several different possible currents - I(V) is not a single valued function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is that,given this, how can we say that a conductor
>   doesn't obey Ohm's law.

For an example of how, consider a conductor with a *voltage dependent resistance*, e.g., a [varistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varistor)

> Similarly shouldn't the resistance be then defined to be the
>   derivative of voltage with respect to current?

The derivative $\frac{dV}{dI}$ is called the *differential* or *dynamic* or *small signal* resistance as opposed to the *static* resistance $\frac{V}{I}$.  For an ohmic device, these two resistance measures are equal.

See, for example, [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance_and_conductance#Static_and_differential_resistance) of the Wikipedia article [Electrical resistance and conductance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance_and_conductance):

[image]

> The IV curve of a non-ohmic device (purple). The static resistance at
>   point A is the inverse slope of line B through the origin. The
>   differential resistance at A is the inverse slope of tangent line C.

Answer (score 1):

"Shouldn't everything be having a constant voltage to current ratio at a given point in time [... ?]"

That's not what we mean by $\frac{V}{I}$ = constant. What we do mean is that even when we change $V,$ we find that $I$ changes in such a way that the ratio $\frac{V}{I}$ stays the same. And if we find that the ratio really does stay the same, we say that the conductor is Ohmic.

Answer (score 0):

If voltage and current are proportional at constant temperature then the conductor is ohmic, else it is non ohmic.